# Undefined values in req.body

Tags: node.js, express

When I wanna make a POST req using Postman where I already set the content-type to application/json and I console.log the req.body.name or sth else it only returns **undefined**.
Here's the code: 
*index.js*

```
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECT,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  () => console.log("connected to mongoDB")
);

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.use("/api/user", authRoute);

// Run Server
const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

*auth.js*

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../model/User");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });
  console.log(req.body.name);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: and:
*User.js*
```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
    max: 255,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
    max: 255,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
    max: 1024,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using *body parser* and using only *express.json()* send requests as **raw** then pick **JSON**. The format that you should write looks like this:

`{
   "name": "Some name",
   "lastname": "...."
}`

> Here is how your postman should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install Body parser as:

`npm install --save body-parser`

and then update your index.js file as:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

just add these line after 
// Middleware

```
app.use(express.json());
```

for example 
// Middleware

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded{extended: true})
```

This express setting will allow you to parse html-body